# IHP Haskell field display format Double values

Tags: haskell, ihp

I have a table with a Double field, e.g. `foo`. When I capture numbers like 50 million (`50000000`) and then I want to view my data, I get: `5.0e7`. When I edit the record again, I also view `5.0e7` on the text field.

I can solve the "show" part using a utility function like:

```hs
-- Application/Helper/View.hs

module Application.Helper.View where

import Data.Text (unpack)
-- added format-numbers package as dependency on default.nix
import Data.Text.Format.Numbers
import IHP.ViewPrelude


-- Here you can add functions which are available in all your views

moneyConfiguration :: PrettyCfg
moneyConfiguration = PrettyCfg 2 (Just ',') '.'

showMoneyAmount :: Double -> String
showMoneyAmount d = unpack $ prettyF moneyConfiguration d
```

Then I use it on `Web/View/MyRecord/Show.hs` as:

```html
   ...
   <div class="col">{get #foo myRecord |> showMoneyAmount}</div>
   ...
```

But when rendering the form for creating/editing, I can't get rid of the `5.0e7` value:

```hs
renderForm :: MyRecord -> Html
renderForm myRecord = formFor myRecord [hsx|
    ...
    {(textField #foo)}
    ...
    {submitButton}
|]
```

I wish to have something like:
`{showMoneyAmount <$> (textField #foo)}`

or:
`{(textField #foo){formatValue = showMoneyAmount}}`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you would like to achieve exactly here. Could the [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) module be useful ? Try evaluating `pack (printf "%d" (floor 5.0e7))` for example.

Comment: What is the type of `textField`?

Comment: IHP> :t textField
textField
  :: (?formContext::FormContext model,
      HasField fieldName model value, HasField "meta" model MetaBag,
      InputValue value, KnownSymbol fieldName,
      KnownSymbol (GetModelName model)) =>
     Proxy fieldName -> FormField

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me. I just pushed a fix to https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/commit/6545122bf9129cdb53459c116817776f68bcc300

Therefore this should be fixed with the next IHP release

Comment: if it gets merged it would be great, but we should be able to choose depending on context, e.g. currency values are often formatted with 2 decimal digits and when displaying, using thousand separator, while when editing, the thousand separator feels uncomfortable